# How to store group chat in openfire(XMPP) mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, xmpp, openfire

I have to store group chat conversation in openfire(XMPP) mysql database.I don't see any tables from the openfire database that stores the group conversations.

I have enabled the 'Conversation State Archiving','Message Archiving' from Server-->Archiving-->Archiving Settings and installed 'Monitoring Plugin' but still i am not able to store group chats. Is there any other way to store the group chat in openfire MySQL database.Or any other Plugin that i need to install for the same.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Group conversition will be stored in 'ofmessagearchive' table into mysql.
Make sure you have enabled 'Archive group chats' checkbox from Server-->Archiving-->Archiving Settings. Please refer below screenshoot
[Enable group chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5o6PE.png)

Comment: But we don't have any table like 'ofmessagearChive'. So what should i do for get this table?

Comment: you need to install 'Monitoring Service' plugin for that

Comment: I have installed monitoring plugin and enable "archive one-one" and "archive group chat".It stored one-one chat properly, but it not storing group stanza in ofmessageArchive table.where I am going wrong?please help.

Comment: Exactly group messages are stored in ofmessagearchive table. I am maintaining separate table to store group messages now on the server cron job runs at every 10 seconds but group messages ( chats ) are stored approx after 30 seconds in to ofmessagearchive table.  which causes delay in push notifications is there any way that i can store a group messages into ofmessagearchive table in faster manner ? or any plugin is there for sending group push notifications ?